# VBA: Return SQL procedure print statements?

Tags: t-sql, vba, ms-access

I use the "print" statement in my SQL procs for debugging info. When I execute a SQL proc from within MS Access, can I retrieve the output of my "print" statements?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i dosent think it works
Print dosent allowed this

what you want to do?
any Example or Explains

Mario